# Converting wiki format to XHTML

Tags: php, xhtml, wiki

I have a database storing "wiki formatted" text which I would like to display in XHTML using PHP.

Here is an example output with all the wiki markup:

```
Default text
== Heading 1 ==
=== Heading 2 ===
==== Heading 3 ====
===== Heading 4 =====
====== Heading 5 ======
'''Bold'''
''Italic''
<s>Strikethrough</s>

* List item 1
* List item 2

# Numbered item 1
# Numbered item 2

[[Image:http://domain.com/image.png|Image name]]

[http://google.com Link text goes here]

> Blockquote

<source lang="language">Source code</source>
```

Is that fairly standard wiki syntax? Is there a fairly standard way of interpreting it with PHP?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: dont forget the <nowiki>foobar</nowiki> tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came up with a hack, but it breaks on a lot of things. Is this the best way forward?

**PHP:**

```
function wiki2html($text)
{
        $text = preg_replace('/&lt;source lang=&quot;(.*?)&quot;&gt;(.*?)&lt;\/source&gt;/', '<pre lang="$1">$2</pre>', $text);
        $text = preg_replace('/======(.*?)======/', '<h5>$1</h5>', $text);
        $text = preg_replace('/=====(.*?)=====/', '<h4>$1</h4>', $text);
        $text = preg_replace('/====(.*?)====/', '<h3>$1</h3>', $text);
        $text = preg_replace('/===(.*?)===/', '<h2>$1</h2>', $text);
        $text = preg_replace('/==(.*?)==/', '<h1>$1</h1>', $text);
        $text = preg_replace("/'''(.*?)'''/", '<strong>$1</strong>', $text);
        $text = preg_replace("/''(.*?)''/", '<em>$1</em>', $text);
        $text = preg_replace('/&lt;s&gt;(.*?)&lt;\/s&gt;/', '<strike>$1</strike>', $text);
        $text = preg_replace('/\[\[Image:(.*?)\|(.*?)\]\]/', '<img src="$1" alt="$2" title="$2" />', $text);
        $text = preg_replace('/\[(.*?) (.*?)\]/', '<a href="$1" title="$2">$2</a>', $text);
        $text = preg_replace('/&gt;(.*?)\n/', '<blockquote>$1</blockquote>', $text);

        $text = preg_replace('/\* (.*?)\n/', '<ul><li>$1</li></ul>', $text);
        $text = preg_replace('/<\/ul><ul>/', '', $text);

        $text = preg_replace('/# (.*?)\n/', '<ol><li>$1</li></ol>', $text);
        $text = preg_replace('/<\/ol><ol>/', '', $text);

        $text = str_replace("\r\n\r\n", '</p><p>', $text);
        $text = str_replace("\r\n", '<br/>', $text);
        $text = '<p>'.$text.'</p>';
        return $text;
}
```

**Input:**

```
Default text
== Heading 1 ==
=== Heading 2 ===
==== Heading 3 ====
===== Heading 4 =====
====== Heading 5 ======
'''Bold'''
''Italic''
<s>Strikethrough</s>

* List item 1
* List item 2

# Numbered item 1
# Numbered item 2

[[Image:http://domain.com/image.png|Image name]]

[http://google.com Link text goes here]

> Blockquote

<source lang="language">Source code</source>
```

**Output:**

```
<p>
  Default text<br/>
  <h1> Heading 1 </h1><br/>
  <h2> Heading 2 </h2><br/>
  <h3> Heading 3 </h3><br/>
  <h4> Heading 4 </h4><br/>
  <h5> Heading 5 </h5><br/>
  <strong>Bold</strong><br/>
  <em>Italic</em><br/>
  <strike>Strikethrough</strike>
</p>

<p>
  <ul>
    <li>List item 1</li>
    <li>List item 2</li>
  </ul>
  <br/>
  <ol>
    <li>Numbered item 1</li>
    <li>Numbered item 2</li>
  </ol>
  <br/>
  <img src="http://domain.com/image.png" alt="Image name" title="Image name" />
</p>

<p>
  <a href="http://google.com" title="Link text goes here">Link text goes here</a>
</p>

<p>
  <blockquote> Blockquote</blockquote><br/>
  <pre lang="language">Source code</pre><br/>
</p>
```

Comment: It looks like my string format isn't *standard* wikiformat so I'm going to arrogantly accept my own answer. If anyone can improve my code please feel free!

Comment: I've used a cut down verson of your code to do some wikitext parsing, the last paragraph isn't closed with your version. I used a slightly modified end:

$text = str_replace("\r\n\r\n", '</p><p>', $text,$count);
if($count>0) $text .= '</p>';

Comment: Added horizontal line  `$text = preg_replace('/----/', '<hr />', $text); `

Comment: Don't forget the cleanup!

`$text = preg_replace('%<p>(<h\\d>.*?</h\\d>)</p>%', '$1', $text);`
`$text = preg_replace('%<p>(<ul>.*?</ul>)</p>%', '$1', $text);`
`$text = preg_replace('%<p>(<ol>.*?</ol>)</p>%', '$1', $text);`

Answer (score 4):

I would say that the most standard wiki-like format around today is [markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/). There are libraries available for almost any platform, [including PHP](http://michelf.com/projects/php-markdown/).

Comment: markdown looks fantastic! As does the PHP class. Unfortunately the formatting doesn't match my string - if I had control over the data I would choose markdown :)

Comment: markdown does not do the basics, you have to download another file to do that. Still looking for a basic all inclusive wiki2html convertor

Answer (score 3):

[MediaWiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki) is written in PHP and licensed under [GPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_General_Public_License). So you just could take the [WikiText](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikitext) converter and use it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that seems like a fairly standard wiki format. I've created several PHP wiki solutions using the PEAR package Text_Wiki. It does just what you want, and you can even expand it to support any custom syntax and translate according to any rule.

http://pear.php.net/package/Text_Wiki

Comment: text_wiki also looks great! But my formatting doesn't match that. My string is non-standard I suspect

Comment: You can add your own rules to text_wiki too. Then you can support any typ of Wiki.

Answer (score -1):

It's going to depend very much on what language you are using to parse.

Client-side with Javascript?

Server Side with ASP or PHP?

Comment: I'm using PHP. I did add it to the tags but forgot to mention in the question!