# Is there any existing project that provide basic library convert wiki text to html using PHP?

Tags: php, wiki

I know there's lots of projects (like Mediawiki , PHPWiki , etc ) provide full solution about WIKI , but I think they provide too much than I actually need.

All of them looks complicated and that's not what I need.

All I need is just a simple library provide functionality that convert wiki textile to HTML so I can embed them into my own project.

Thanks.

Comment: Markdown processors are out there (not quite the same as wiki markup, but may satisfy your needs). Try this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885532/safe-markdown-processor-for-php

Comment: See also [PHP Wiki Regex Scripts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172188/php-wiki-regex-scripts) and [Converting wiki format to XHTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252118/converting-wiki-format-to-xhtml)